# Not a Statement Error - Where did I go wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, input, jcreator

So, I am very new at coding but have a college assignment to create a Word Manipulator. I am supposed to get a string and an INT from the user and invert every Nth word, according to the int input. 
I am following steps and am stuck with this error at line 38 (the start of my last FOR LOOP). The compiler is giving me an Not an Statement Error in this line but I cant see where I went wrong.
Could someone gimme a light, please?
ps: I am not allowed to use Token or inverse().

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class assignment3 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // BOTH INPUTS WERE TAKEN
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String stringInput;
    int intInput;
    System.out.println("Please enter a sentence");
    stringInput = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer from 1 to 10. \n We will invert every word in that position for you!");
    intInput = input.nextInt();
    int counter = 1;

    // ALL CHARS NOW ARE LOWERCASE
    String lowerCaseVersion = stringInput.toLowerCase();


    // SPLIT THE STRING INTO ARRAY OF WORDS
    String [] arrayOfWords = null;
    String delimiter = " ";
    arrayOfWords = lowerCaseVersion.split(delimiter);
    for(int i=0; i< arrayOfWords.length; i++){
        System.out.println(arrayOfWords[i]);
        // THIS RETURNS AN ARRAY WITH ALL THE WORDS FROM THE INPUT
    }

    // IF THE INTEGER INPUT IS BIGGER THAN THE STRING.LENGTH, OUTPUT A MESSAGE
    // THIS PART IS WORKING BUT I MIGHT WANT TO PUT IT IN A LOOP AND ASK FOR INPUT AGAIN
    if (intInput > arrayOfWords.length){
        System.out.println("There are not enough words in your sentence!");
    }

    // NOW I NEED TO REVERSE EVERY NTH WORD BASED ON THE USER INPUT
    //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
    for(int i=(intInput-1); i<arrayOfWords.length; (i+intInput)){
        char invertedWord[] = new char[arrayOfWords.length()];
        for(int i=0; i < arrayOfWords.length();i++){
            ch[i]=arrayOfWords.charAt(i);
        }
        for(int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
            System.out.print(invertedWord[i]);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - Pleas do not use all upper case words in your caption. This is considered SHOUTING and this is simply unpolite.

Comment: Fixed title. Thank you

Comment: *" I am following steps and am stuck with this error at line 38 (the FOR LOOP) "* I don't see any error here. please explain (in the question).

Comment: My compiler is giving me an Statement Error at the line where my last For Loop starts (I made a comment in the code to specify where the error is been found.) I cant see any errors.

Answer (score 0):

(i+intInput) isn't a statement. That's like saying 12. Perhaps you mean i=i+intInput or i+=intInput which assigns a value to a variable

Answer (score 0):

well, for one thing, i dont see "s" (from s.length()) initiated anywhere in your code.